# How to record presence/absence of splitted elements of large strings in individual dataframe columns

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a dataframe with long and messy strings of household amenities. I want to break the strings into unique amenities, create for each unique amenity a new column in the dataframe, and record in the new columns the presence/absence of the individual amenities in the strings.
Using nested `for` loops I've found a way to accomplish the task. However, what I'd like to know is how the same result can be obtained using one of the `apply` family of functions or a `dplyr` method to avoid the loops.

Reproducible data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  amenities = c('{"Wireless Internet","Wheelchair accessible",Kitchen,Elevator,"Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating}',
                '{TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Smoking allowed","Pets allowed"}',
                '{"Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,"Family/kid friendly","Smoke detector",Carbon monoxide}',
                '{Washer,Dryer,Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,"Laptop friendly workspace"}'))
```

What I've done so far is this:

```
amenities_clean <- gsub('[{}"]', '', df$amenities) # remove unwanted stuff 
amenities_split <- strsplit(amenities_clean, ",") # split rows into individual amenities
amenities_unique <- unique(unlist(strsplit(amenities_clean, ","))) # get a list of unique amenities 
df[amenities_unique] <- NA # set up the columns for each amenity
```

To record in the new columns whether the individual amenities are present or absent in the strings, I'm using `str_detect` as well as nested `for` loops:

```
# record presence/absence of individual amenities in each new column:
library(stringr)
for(i in 1:ncol(df[amenities_unique])){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[amenities_unique][j,i] <- 
      ifelse(str_detect(amenities_split[j], names(df[amenities_unique][i])), 1, 0)
  }
}
```

While this produces warnings, they seem not to be harmful, as the result looks okay:

```
df
  id                                                                                                amenities Wireless Internet
1  1        {"Wireless Internet","Wheelchair accessible",Kitchen,Elevator,"Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating}                 1
2  2 {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Smoking allowed","Pets allowed"}                 1
3  3              {"Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,"Family/kid friendly","Smoke detector",Carbon monoxide}                 0
4  4                                    {Washer,Dryer,Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,"Laptop friendly workspace"}                 0
  Wheelchair accessible Kitchen Elevator Buzzer/wireless intercom Heating TV Cable TV Internet Air conditioning Smoking allowed
1                     1       1        1                        1       1  0        0        1                0               0
2                     0       1        0                        0       0  1        1        1                1               1
3                     0       0        0                        1       1  0        0        0                0               0
4                     0       0        0                        0       0  0        0        0                0               0
  Pets allowed Family/kid friendly Smoke detector Carbon monoxide Washer Dryer Essentials Shampoo Hangers Laptop friendly workspace
1            0                   0              0               0      0     0          0       0       0                         0
2            1                   0              0               0      0     0          0       0       0                         0
3            0                   1              1               1      0     0          0       0       0                         0
4            0                   0              0               0      1     1          1       1       1                         1
```

Given the warnings and given the convolutedness of nested loops, how can the same result be obtained using a function from the `apply`family of functions or using `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you clean the amenities , you can use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape`.

```
df$amenities_clean <- gsub('[{}"]', '', df$amenities) 
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(df, "amenities_clean", type = "character", fill = 0)
```

---

To solve it using one of the apply functions we can do :

```
temp <- strsplit(df$amenities_clean, ",")
amenities_unique <- unique(unlist(temp))
cbind(df, t(sapply(temp, function(x) 
                   table(factor(x, levels = amenities_unique)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful. Is there no way to use an *apply function? I've been testing numerous ones, one being this: `df[amenities_unique]<- lapply(df[amenities_unique], 
                              function(x) ifelse(str_detect(strsplit(df$amenities_clean, ","), names(x)), 1, 0))`but doesn't return the desired result.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I thought `cSplit_e` is simpler and cleaner. I have updated the answer using one of the apply method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this gives the output you need:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(amenities = str_replace_all(amenities, '["{}]', '')) %>% 
  separate_rows(amenities, sep = ",") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = amenities, values_from = amenities, values_fn = list(amenities = is.character)) %>% 
  mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
```

Result is:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 22
     id `Wireless Inter~ `Wheelchair acc~ Kitchen Elevator `Buzzer/wireles~ Heating    TV `Cable TV` Internet `Air conditioni~ `Smoking allowe~
  <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1                1                1       1        1                1       1     0          0        0                0                0
2     2                1                0       1        0                0       0     1          1        1                1                1
3     3                0                0       0        0                1       1     0          0        0                0                0
4     4                0                0       0        0                0       0     0          0        0                0                0
# ... with 10 more variables: `Pets allowed` <dbl>, `Family/kid friendly` <dbl>, `Smoke detector` <dbl>, `Carbon monoxide` <dbl>, Washer <dbl>,
#   Dryer <dbl>, Essentials <dbl>, Shampoo <dbl>, Hangers <dbl>, `Laptop friendly workspace` <dbl>
```